# Python ошибка TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, pygame

Это мой код

```
def draw_rect_platform(cell_id, color, lst):
    if isinstance(color, str):
        color = pygame.Color(color)
    elif isinstance(color, list):
        color = pygame.Color(color[0], color[1], color[2])
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in range(len(lst[i])):
            if lst[i][j][5] == cell_id:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (lst[i][j][0], lst[i][j][1]),
                                 (lst[i][j][2], lst[i][j][3]))


cells = cell_lst((10, 10), 50)
print(cells)
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
draw_rect_platform(6, (255, 0, 0), cells)
```

Список такой:

```
[[[0, 0, 50, 50, ['properties'], 1], [50, 0, 100, 50, ['properties'], 2], [100, 0, 150, 50, ['properties'], 3], [150, 0, 200, 50, ['properties'], 4],...]
```

Вот ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tyapk/platformer/render.py", line 91, in <module> 
    draw_rect_platform(6, (255, 0, 0), cells)
  File "C:/Users/tyapk/platformer/render.py", line 82, in draw_rect_platform
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (lst[i][j][0], lst[i][j][1]),
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если смотреть в документации по [`pygame.draw.rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect), то можно увидеть, что третьим параметром должен передаваться объект [`Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect), у вас вместо этого передается два `tuple`, похоже что в второй `tuple` попадает в параметр `width`.

Правильный вариант должен быть таким:

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect((lst[i][j][0], lst[i][j][1]),
                                            (lst[i][j][2], lst[i][j][3])))
```

или

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(lst[i][j][0], lst[i][j][1],
                                            lst[i][j][2], lst[i][j][3]))
```

или (сокращенный вариант, будет работать если элемент двумерного массива `lst` содержит ровно 4 элемента):

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(*lst[i][j]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы передаете в поле rect кортеж из двух списков. Ожидается несколько интов.

```
Rect(left, top, width, height)
```